# Spring Boot @DataJpaTest causing `No ServletContext set` error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When running a test with the `@DataJpaTest` annotation, this exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
```

How do I set a `ServletContext`?

**I have this test:**

```
package com.example.thing.unit.services;

import com.example.thing.services.StorageService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Tag("unit")
public class StorageServiceTest {

  @Autowired private StorageService storageService;

  @Test
  public void whenFindMessageById_thenReturnMessage() {

    final var messages = storageService.saveRandomMessages(1);
    final var id = messages.get(0).getId();
    final var message = storageService.getMessage(id);

    assertTrue(message.isPresent());
    assertEquals(id, message.get().getId());
  }
}
```

**And these Spring dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**Full test output:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$0(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:69)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:486)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48901ac4.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$30(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48901ac4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b6869344.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48901ac4.resourceHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 73 more
```

**Adding @SpringBootTest to the test class renders this error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of
@BootstrapWith for test class [com.barrowts.omniaapi.unit.services.StorageServiceTest]:
[@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=class org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), 
@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]
```

**Also adding a `@ContextConfiguration` annotation, with a configuration class, as [shown in this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webappconfiguration), has no effect.**

Comment: I added an issue in Spring Boot to improve this error message: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16936

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Boot and the error message is quite clear. What is interesting is why it even tries to instantiate this class for an `@DataJpaTest` as it should only add the JPA stuff and leave everything else alone. Start by removing the `@RunWith` as that is for JUnit4 and you are using JUnit 5 (And the `@DataJpaTest` is annotated with the correct annotation already). Can you add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class to your question?

Answer (score 13):

For loading webapplication context use the annotations :

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)
```

The `@WebAppConfiguration` annotation will setup a mock servlet which should fix your error and  user the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation if you want to load additional configurations to your context.

You are facing this issue because when using the annotation `@DataJpaTest` regular `@Component` beans are not loaded in to the context.This annotation only scans for entity and configures only the Spring Data JPA repositories.So , if you are using other beans in your test you will have to provide those beans in another way.Here, you are autowiring beans which may not be present in the context.Spring provides the `@DataJpaTest` annotation to test the **Spring Data JPA repositories, or any other JPA-related components**.

Also, if you are using `@SpringBootTest` , omit the `@DataJpaTest` annotation as `@SpringBootTest` is already meta-annotated.But this annotation is more suitable for running integration test cases.

`@ContextConfiguration` can be used to load test configurations, so i suggest that you load the service bean needed to run your test using a test configuration.

Comment: Adding `@WebAppConfiguration` has no effect. Adding `@ContextConfiguration` with a `WebConfig.class` as described in this Baeldung article also has no effect: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webappconfiguration

Comment: May I suggest loading the whole Spring Context using @SpringBootTest annotation (and no @DataJpaTest). This won't be as efficient but we can wait until OP obtains some maturity with Spring and SpringBoot.

Comment: Can you provide the StorageService class in your question ? I think you are using the @DataJpaTest annotation for a usecase that it is not intended to be used for.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular instance, because the `StorageService` has a `@Service` tag in its definition, that probably means that you need to use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation in the test to load the entire Spring Boot context.

The `@JpaDataTest` annotation doesn't load enough context to successfully load a `@Service`.

It would help if that stupid exception provided more information. Like `No ServletContext set when trying to load this particular thing`.

Comment: The stack trace contains that information. It shows that it's `WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping` the requires a `ServletContext` to have been set. A `@DataJpaTest` should not include any Web MVC infrastructure. Perhaps you have used `@EnableWebMvc` on your main application class that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`?

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same problem due to an extended WebMvcConfigurationSupport class in my application, and finally I got the solution.

As suggested in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html)

```
If you are looking to load your full application configuration, but use an embedded database, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined with @AutoConfigureTestDatabase rather than this annotation.
```

That is, you should use @SpringBootTest + @AutoConfigureTestDatabase instead of @DataJpaTest.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using only repository interface in my test class and I was still getting the error. On more closer inspection, I found that I mistakenly added `@EnableWebMvc` annotation on `@SpringBootApplication` class, and removing this duplicate annotation solved the issue.

I know `@SpringBootApplication` will auto-configure all the components found on classpath and `@EnableWebMvc` is duplicate, I added it previously to try another issue and forgot to remove it.

I never thought this duplicity would cause my test to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to autowire a ServletContext bean into the scope (of the test).

Comment: Adding `  @Autowired private ServletContext servletContext;` in to the `StorageService` class has no effect.

Comment: Try putting @SpringBootTest at the class level. Yet, it will load the whole spring application context, which may be heavy.

Comment: That causes another error: `Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.barrowts.omniaapi.unit.services.StorageServiceTest]`, full output was added to the end of my question.

Comment: @Neil , mind your language. Actually, I was as frustrated as you were but this indeed is because "No ServletContext" is "set". Spring boot is responsible to set it but your unit-test does not load the whole Spring boot. Neither you write some test set-up so "ServletContext" is indeed not "set".

Comment: It's true that the `ServletContext` isn't set, but the error message is still relatively useless. It should provide a hint, and there should be documentation explaining how to do it. I've tried using `@WebAppConfiguration` and `@ContextConfiguration` with a configuration class. I've tried whatever annotation loads the whole SpringBoot application context. Nothing has any effect.

Comment: Using only `@SpringBootTest` annotation without `@JpaDataTest` seemed to work.

Comment: This is a literal answer to the question - "to autowire a ServletContext bean".

Answer (score 0):

Couple of years late, but...

A workaround before Spring team fix this (I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0 and I've just seen this, so no holding our breaths for a fix) is to add a `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to your `@DataJpaTest` annotated test slice class, set an active profile for that (and similar) test classes (`@ActiveProfile("test-slice")`),  and add a profile to the (main) class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` excluding the profile used in test slice (`@Profile("!test-slice")`):

```
@ActiveProfile("test-slice")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@DataJpaTest
@Tag("unit")
public class StorageServiceTest {
...
}

@EnableMvc
@Profile("!test-slice")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
...
}
```